# Separate get request being generated for every request

Tags: http, nginx, get

I have a site that's embedded inside an iframe.

On occasion I'm seeing a phantom get request generated for each get or post.

The nginx logs show this occurring, notice there is a get request sent immediately after the post:

```
XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [06/Oct/2012:20:55:47 +0000] "POST /website_widget/users HTTP/1.1" 200 1996 "http://subdomain.mysite.com/website_wi
dget/users/sign_up" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [06/Oct/2012:20:55:47 +0000] "GET /website_widget/users HTTP/1.1" 404 781 "http://subdomain.mysite.com/website_widg
et/users" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"

XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [06/Oct/2012:20:55:53 +0000] "POST /website_widget/users HTTP/1.1" 200 1993 "http://subdomain.mysite.com/website_wi
dget/users" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
XX.XXX.XXX.XX - - [06/Oct/2012:20:55:53 +0000] "GET /website_widget/users HTTP/1.1" 404 781 "http://subdomain.mysite.com/website_widg
et/users" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"
```

This also happens with standard get requests too. From my rails logs I can see:

```
Started GET "/website_widget/users/sign_in" for XX.XX.XXX.XX at 2012-10-06 20:45:35 +0000
[b7e895726057452d0af6a2ac5cd1668d] Processing by WebsiteWidget::MyController#new as HTML

Started GET "/website_widget/users/sign_in" for XX.XX.XXX.XX at 2012-10-06 20:45:37 +0000
[b20e57fcc205ee6cf958589ab1660c9f] Processing by WebsiteWidget::MyController#new as */*
```

Notice in the `*/*` for the second log entry, which suggests the mime type is not set to html or not set at all.

Had anyone come across this kind of thing before? Or got any idea how I can debug it further. I'm proving quite difficult to recreate.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this was caused by a firefox plugin. Probably a site ranking plugin of some description.